# Get option value depending on other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following `html` markup:

```
<div class="wrap_select">
    <span class="select" id="selectdateRange">Today, 25 March, Sun</span>
    <select class="styled" id="dateRange" name="dateRange">
        <option value="25.03.2012">Today, 25 March, Sun</option> // "current"
        <option value="26.03.2012">Tomorrow, 26 March, Fr</option>
        <option value="27.03.2012">27 March, Tu</option>
        <option value="28.03.2012">28 March, We</option>
        <option value="29.03.2012">29 March, Th</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The `<span class="select">` contain text from `select` options.
How can I get value of the "current" select?

For marup above the result must be `25.03.2012`.

Comment: if you just want selected option value.. try "$('select.styled').val()"... you expectation is not very clear..

Comment: That looks like a plugin that replaces the `select` with a custom-styled element. If it's done right, it should be updating the `select` in the background, so just `$('#dateRange').val()` should suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var text = $.trim($('#selectdateRange').text());
var theWinner = $('select option').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == text;
}).val();

alert(theWinner);
```

​
[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CMA5Q/)

Comment: I had to call my answer an alternative after this.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GVzvj/) what you want?

```
$('.select').html($('.styled option:selected').val());

$('.styled').live('change', function() {
    $('.select').html($(this).val())
});
```

Comment: Guys, Thanks for your comment. Just I want to know if we post our code here what is the purpose of JSFiddle? Isn't better to see the code in action? If I'm wrong please let me know so I can change the way I'm answering questions here!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way that does what you want

```
function findCurrent() {
    var currentText = $('span').text();
    var currentVal;
    $("select option").each(function(k,v) {
       if($(this).text()==currentText) {
           currentVal = $(this).val();
           return false;
       }
    });
    return currentVal;
}
// Usage
console.log(findCurrent());
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/CMA5Q/2/)

Comment: **1.** `$("select").find("option")` => `$("select option")` **2.** `return $this.val();` => `return $(this).val();`

Comment: @gdoron, I was fixing the typos and titbit and creating a demo. Man you are quick. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.select').text($('#dateRange option:selected').val());
```

this should work for you